# WCF to Database Connectivity

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, service, ria

I am developing a businees application, which queries lots of record.
Which connectivity is good to retrieve? 
1. LINQ to SQL or 
2. LINQ to Entity or
3. RIA Service or 
4. Others ?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a WCF service to expose a database to other programs, you could try [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx). With this, consumers of your service can use LINQ syntax to send complex queries to the service, which will execute them on the database and return the results REST-style, formatted in an XML dialect called OData that can be read by any XML parser--or transparently read and converted into objects by a WCF Data Services client.